# Why isn't box shadow displaying correctly on Chrome mobile?

Tags: css

I have a very basic static HTML web page with borders and box shadow on a containing element.

The box shadow displays correctly on desktop browsers but on the Chrome mobile browser (only tested on Chrome) the box shadow on the bottom edge of the element is much larger than it should be.

There are also inconsistencies in how it displays. Sometimes when I first load the page I don't see the box-shadow and then it will suddenly appear.

I've checked for errors in the HTML and CSS but can't find anything wrong.

This is the code I'm using for the box shadow:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(255,255,0,0.5);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(255,255,0,0.5);
box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(255,255,0,0.5);
```

I've recreated the page on Codepen:
https://s.codepen.io/sean-collins/debug/GRKvBeP/YvkgOeODyLNk

I've changed the colors of the borders and color and size of the box-shadow to make it easier to see them but otherwise everything is the same as on the actual page.

Comment: Try to add some margin at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it didn't seem to make any difference.